# Show that a bounded integral operator on $L_2$ maps $L_2$ functions to continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $K(t,s)$ be a continuous function on $L_2([a,b])$, and let $A \in L(L_2[a,b])$ be the integral operator:
$$(Af)(t) = \int_a^b K(t,s)f(s)ds$$

I want to show that for any function $f \in L_2[a,b])$, the operator on the function $Af$ is always continuous.

I managed to show that $\{ Af \}_{f \in M}$ is pre-compact in $C[a,b]$ when $M$ is a set of continuous and bounded functions.

I also get that in this case $\overline {\{ Af \}_{f \in M}}$ is compact, and since $A$ is an integral operator then it's a compact operator.

I would have wanted to somehow represent $Af$ as a limit of continuous functions, but I am not sure exactly how to begin.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Holder's inequality, you can directly verify that
\begin{align*}
|Af(t)-Af(s)|&=\left|\int\limits_a^b (K(t,z)-K(s,z))f(z)\, dz\right|\\
&\leq \int\limits_a^b |K(t,z)-K(s,z)||f(z)|\, dz\leq \|K(t,\cdot)-K(s,\cdot)\|_{L^2}\|f\|_{L^2}\\&\leq \max_{z\in [a,b]}|K(t,z)-K(s,z)|(b-a)^{1/2}\|f\|_{L^2}
\end{align*} Continuity now follows immediately from the continuity of $K$.

Comment: but what about $||f||_{L^2}$? Since it's not necessarily continuous I can't say its norm is bounded

Comment: Since $f$ is in $L^2$, $\|f\|_{L^2}$ is finite.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy Schwartz,
$$\|Af\|_{L^2}\leq \|K\|_{L^2}\|f\|_{L^2},$$
and thus, $A$ is continuous.